# Uncaught exception PHPExcel_Writer_Exception with message File zip

Tags: php, phpexcel, fatal-error

I'm getting this error while loading a file to write into **PHPExcel**,
the file size is 615KB's

```
( ! ) Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PHPExcel_Writer_Exception' with message 'File zip://C:\wamp\www\iON\Files\MISReport_PUN 01 HODEV PANC W MH PUN.xlsx#xl/media/image1.png does not exist' in C:\wamp\www\iON\Excel\PHPExcel\Writer\Excel2007\ContentTypes.php on line 242
( ! ) PHPExcel_Writer_Exception: File zip://C:\wamp\www\iON\Files\MISReport_PUN 01 HODEV PANC W MH PUN.xlsx#xl/media/image1.png does not exist in C:\wamp\www\iON\Excel\PHPExcel\Writer\Excel2007\ContentTypes.php on line 242
```

What could be the possible reason?

Comment: Are you sure that you're getting this error while `loading` the file, and not when actually `writing` it?

Comment: The error occurs when writing the excel file to the location. There is little help on this matter on the internet. Is this a bug with PHPExcel?

Comment: @MarkBaker - am trying to load the file to write, getting this error while loading it.

Comment: @mithilatw - yes it is the stable version of PHPExcel

Comment: I am getting the same error during editing.

Comment: I believe this may be answer to your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23951597/925196

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the file is deleted

```
if (file_exists($pFilename)) {
unlink($pFilename);
}
```

These problems are fixed here https://github.com/nekulin/PHPExcel

Comment: Thanks.

I just replaced my old PHPExcel Folder with the new one (from GitHub) and it worked.